# Power BI new column sum if same ID

Tags: powerbi, sum, sumifs

I have two tables in Power BI:

[image]

I am searching for a DAX function for Table2 which sums up all values for each ID. How can I do it?

Thank u!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using DAX function summarize

```
Table = SUMMARIZE(Data, Data[ID], "Kilo/ID", SUM(Data[Kilo]))
```

[image]